# How to integrate LiqPay into Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I will try to integrate LiqPay in flutter but it does not have a detailed document so, it is possible to link LiqPay in flutter?

Comment: Better try to ask some customer support on their site that they have some provided sdk or api for you to use their services and others. If they do then better you the one will contact them for futher info and instruction.

Answer (score 1):

According to my research, there are no packages available for Liqpay in flutter
and Liqpay also doesn't provide any SDK. So I have created flutter widgets and written nodejs API to solve this issue. Liqpay provide only API connection.